# MySQL - Pulling data from another table through "JOIN"

Tags: mysql, lua

So, I'm new at Lua, and I'm new at SQL queries, and I've tried most stuff, but couldn't get it to work.

My cody is:

```
RegisterServerEvent('police:checkingPlate')
AddEventHandler('police:checkingPlate', function(plate)
    local executed_query = MySQL:executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_vehicle JOIN users ON user_vehicle.identifier = users.identifier WHERE vehicle_plate = '@plate'", { ['@plate'] = plate })
    local result = MySQL:getResults(executed_query, {'Nom'}, "indentifier")
    if (result[1]) then
        for _, v in ipairs(result) do
            TriggerClientEvent('chatMessage', source, 'STATEN', {255, 0, 0}, "Nummerpladen "..plate.." er registreret til ".. v.Nom)
        end
    else
        TriggerClientEvent('chatMessage', source, 'STATEN', {255, 0, 0}, "Nummerpladen "..plate.." er ikke registreret i databasen")
    end
end)
```

What I'm trying to do, is get "Nom" to post into "v.Nom" from the users-table, and not user_vehicle, but still keep the Plate-data from user_vehicle.

Been trying swapping around user_vehicle.identifier with users:identifier, been trying to change identifier to users.identifier, but no luck.

I'm new to this, so just tips on how I would be able to do it is enough, and I'll try from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from `user` table than your query should start from `SELECT * FROM user [rest of query]`.